# How to resolve this error 'critical error accessing file <file_name>' in Trace32

Tags: debugging, trace32, lauterbach

I am currently working on a practice script. One of the function of the script is to print the values of a set of structure values into a file using the "winprint.v.v" command. The corresponding part of the script includes the following commands:

```
WinPrint.v.v %m.1 %r.2 %Hex val1
WinPrint.v.v %m.1 %r.2 %Hex val2
WinPrint.v.v %m.1 %r.2 %Hex val3
WinPrint.v.v %m.1 %r.2 %Hex val4
WinPrint.v.v %m.1 %r.2 %Hex val5
WinPrint.v.v %m.1 %r.2 %Hex val6
WinPrint.v.v %m.1 %r.2 %Hex val7
```

When I execute the script, only the first 2-3 commands of above code are executed before encountering an error. I am aware that in T32, the current command is executed even if the preceding command has not fully executed.

I tried to put some wait statements in between each of the commands. but it didn't work. I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this error.

Comment: File is locally available or it is at some network location ?

Comment: Can you share code snip where you are opening file as well.

Comment: Files are at network location

Comment: There is printer.File command above winprints Commands( which are showed above)

Comment: I have faced this issue , when multiple clients were accessing the same network file location. I am not fully aware but there is some limitation in windows. Generating file locally and updating network file at once generally works for me. but it is still a workaround not proper fix.

Comment: Let me know if it worked for you. I will put it as an answer if working.